# Context-free grammar for L = { b^n c^n a^n , n>=1}

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I have a language L, which is defined as: L = { b^n c^n a^n , n>=1}
The corresponding grammar would be able to create words such as:
bca
bbccaa
bbbcccaaa
...
How would such a grammar look like? Making two variables dependent of each other is relatively simple, but I have trouble with doing it for three.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer? How can you tell?

Comment: This is a classic example of a language that isn't context free

Comment: This is one of most commonly used examples of non-context free languages. http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs220/Notes/NonCFL.pdf

Comment: The whole language actually looks like this:
L = {a^m b^n c^n a^(m+n) |m ≥ 0,n ≥ 1}

so I have split the problem in two parts:
  - adding "a" to the left and right
  - adding "b","c" and "a" together

Is this still non-context-free or have I made a mistake?

Comment: @infecto: the standard proof that `a^n b^n c^n` is not a CFL uses the pumping lemma; it is often used to teach the pumping lemma, I believe. A very similar proof should work for the language in your comment, so I don't believe it is context-free either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `L = { b^n c^n a^n , n>=1}`

As pointed out in the comments, this is a canonical example of a language which is not context free. It can be shown using the pumping lemma for context-free languages. Basically, consider a string like `b^p c^p a^p` where `p` is the pumping length and then show no matter what part you pump, you will throw off the balance (basically, the size of the part that's pumped is less than `p`, so it cannot "span" all three symbols to keep them in sync).

> `L = {a^m b^n c^n a^(m+n) |m ≥ 0,n ≥ 1}`

As suggested in the comments, this is not context free either. It can be shown using the pumping lemma for context-free languages as well. However, given a proof (or acceptance) of the above, there is an easier way. Recall that the intersection of a regular language and a context-free language must be context free. Assume `L` is context-free. Then so must be its intersection with the regular language `(b+c)(b+c)* a*`. However, that intersection can be expressed as `b^n c^n a^n` (since `m` is forced to be zero), which we know is not context-free, a contradiction. Therefore, our assumption was wrong and `L` is not context free either.